# Does moving ownership copy the `self` struct when calling a function?

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization

In my example below does `cons.push(...)` ever copy the `self` parameter?

Or is `rustc` intelligent enough to realize that the values coming from lines `#a` and `#b` can always use the same stack space and no copying needs to occur (except for the obvious `i32` copies)?

In other words, does a call to `Cons.push(self, ...)` always create a copy of `self` as ownership is being moved? Or does the `self` struct always stay in place on the stack?

References to documentation would be appreciated.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cons<T, U>(T, U);

impl<T, U> Cons<T, U> {
    fn push<V>(self, value: V) -> Cons<Self, V> {
        Cons(self, value)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cons = Cons(1, 2); // #a
    let cons = cons.push(3); // #b
    println!("{:?}", cons); // #c
}
```

The implication in my example above is whether or not the `push(...)` function grows more expensive to call each time we add a line like `#b` at the rate of `O(n^2)` (if `self` is copied each time) or at the rate of `O(n)` (if `self` stays in place).

I tried implementing the `Drop` trait and noticed that both `#a` and `#b` were dropped *after* `#c`. To me this seems to indicate that `self` stays in place in this example, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: Note that optimizations done by the compiler is highly undefined. They might even change upon structure complexity, size, compilation backend, etc. Wasting time studying these subject-to-change behaviour might not give you any guarantee when scenarios change, and is usually only useful after you have profiled the program and confirmed it to be the major source of performance issues. For example, if the compiler decides to inline your code (which depends on a bunch of factors), it might optimize more (or less) than not inlining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, trust in the compiler! Rust + LLVM is a very powerful combination that often produces surprisingly efficient code. And it will improve even more in time.

> In other words, does a call to Cons.push(self, ...) always create a copy of self as ownership is being moved? Or does the self struct always stay in place on the stack?

`self` cannot stay in place because the new value returned by the `push` method has type `Cons<Self, V>`, which is essentially a tuple of `Self` and `V`. Although [tuples don't have any memory layout guarantees](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#tuple-layout), I strongly believe they can't have their elements scattered arbitrarily in memory. Thus, `self` and `value` must both be moved into the new structure.

Above paragraph assumed that `self` was placed firmly on the stack before calling `push`. The compiler actually has enough information to know it should reserve enough space for the final structure. Especially with function inlining this becomes a very likely optimization.

> The implication in my example above is whether or not the push(...) function grows more expensive to call each time we add a line like #b at the rate of O(n^2) (if self is copied each time) or at the rate of O(n) (if self stays in place).

Consider two functions ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=76d81b8c0fa7b92f95884b032d8b559e)):

```
pub fn push_int(cons: Cons<i32, i32>, x: i32) -> Cons<Cons<i32, i32>, i32> {
    cons.push(x)
}

pub fn push_int_again(
    cons: Cons<Cons<i32, i32>, i32>,
    x: i32,
) -> Cons<Cons<Cons<i32, i32>, i32>, i32> {
    cons.push(x)
}
```

`push_int` adds a third element to a `Cons` and `push_int_again` adds a fourth element.

`push_int` compiles to the following assembly in Release mode:

```
movq    %rdi, %rax
movl    %esi, (%rdi)
movl    %edx, 4(%rdi)
movl    %ecx, 8(%rdi)
retq
```

And `push_int_again` compiles to:

```
movq    %rdi, %rax
movl    8(%rsi), %ecx
movl    %ecx, 8(%rdi)
movq    (%rsi), %rcx
movq    %rcx, (%rdi)
movl    %edx, 12(%rdi)
retq
```

You don't need to understand assembly to see that pushing the fourth element requires more instructions than pushing the third element.

Note that this observation was made for these functions in isolation. Calls like `cons.push(x).push(y).push(...)` are inlined and the assembly grows linearly with one instruction per push.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible for them to optimize away this difference in the future. Assuming the `Cons` struct is laid out in memory like C, the `cons` argument in both of your functions ends up in the beginning of the return value and the other argument ends up at the end (same with my example in OP). So it seems possible for the compiler to recognize that it can just allocate one `Cons<Cons<Cons<i32, i32>, i32>, i32>` on the stack and use that memory for both of your function calls.

Comment: @MattThomas You have a point there. The compiler has not much optimization potential in my two functions because it does not know where and how they will be called. If you do something like `cons.push(x).push(y).push(...` it only adds one instruction per push. The compiler is pretty smart already (for example, `Cons(1, 2)` compiles to a bitcast of an integer constant). If all relevant functions are inlined I think the compiler will know where to put the result without unnecessary moves. No guarantees, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

The ownership of cons in #a type Cons will be transferred in push(). Again the ownership will be transferred to `Cons<Cons,i32>(Cons<T,U>)` type which is shadowed variable cons in #b.

If struct Cons implement Copy, Clone traits it will be copy. Otherwise no copy and you cannot use the original vars after they are moved (or owned) by someone else.

Move semantics:

```
let cons = Cons(1, 2); //Cons(1,2) as resource in memory being pointed by cons
let cons2 = cons; // Cons(1,2)  now pointed by cons2. Problem! as cons also point it. Lets prevent access from cons
println!("{:?}", cons); //error because cons is moved
```

Comment: So does moving ownership necessarily mean either (1) the `self` struct is never copied in memory, or (2) the `self` struct is always copied in memory?

Comment: If Copy trait is implemented, by copy semantics, it will be a copy and you can continue using original copied var. Although compiler might do optimization considering the operation thereafter; the visible affect to the user should be of copy in this case.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the part about the `Copy` trait. But I'm unclear if when an ownership movement takes place whether `self` is necessarily duplicated in (stack) memory or whether `self` necessarily stays in the same location in (stack) memory or whether there is necessarily no guarantee. That's what my OP is about

Comment: With move semantics there is no reason for it to copy it should stay there. The reason existing var is not usable is that, one resource should not be pointed by two pointers (or vars). I think the specs will not talk about that specific detail because compiler keeps optimizing such things over the period.

Comment: `With move semantics there is no reason for it to copy it should stay there` <- this is my intuition as well, but I don't see anything that _necessarily_ makes this the case. For example, the compiler would be quite free to `memcopy` stuff on the stack during an ownership move without anyone being the wiser--it's just a struct, and during an ownership move you know that one piece of code is no longer going to reference it and the next piece of code that will begin to reference it hasn't begun executing yet, so what's to keep the compiler from rearranging things and inserting `memmove` calls

Comment: I have added a snippet above for move semantics. If the struct instance first owned by `cons` in line 1 is now owned by `cons2` in line 2 there is no copy made. If a copy had been created there is no reason to prevent access of struct instance via `cons` in line 3. Because it will not be safe for both cons and cons2 to point to same memory location rust compiler restricts cons. In rust this is at compiler level. In C++ move semantics are not at compile time and you need to implement move constructor and assignment operator to move the resources.